# Why do these two Cypher queries produce different results?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have the following Cypher query (using Neo4j 2.0):

```
MATCH (c:contact) WHERE c.id = "7VpzLRcMN71" WITH c
MATCH (x:task)
WHERE c-[:CONTACT*1..6]->(:projectclients)-[:CONTACT|SUBPROJECT*1..5]->(:project)-->(:tasks)-->x
RETURN x
```

I thought this would only match when `c` is connected to `x` via a path that goes through a `projectclients` node and then through a `project` node and then through a `tasks` node. However, this query matches 4 results when there should be 0.

If I change the query to the following:

```
MATCH (c:contact) WHERE c.id = "7VpzLRcMN71" WITH c
MATCH (x:task), (p:projectclients)
WHERE c-[:CONTACT*1..6]->p-[:CONTACT|SUBPROJECT*1..5]->(:project)-->(:tasks)-->x
RETURN x
```

It works as expected and returns zero results.

Shouldn't these two queries return the same results?

Comment: Perhaps you can share your graph model and the sample data you use the queries with first and the results you get (node-labels and rel-types) ? And you probably want to move the where clause into the MATCH clause to speed it up.

Comment: The WHERE statement includes OR conditions which I don't think I can do in MATCH (I simplified it to the smallest query that produced the incorrect results). Is there somewhere I can send my db file and queries?

Comment: You can zip it and upload to dropbox, or so. If it is small enough you can also send it via email to michael at neotechnology dot com

Comment: Hi Michael, I sent over my graph and queries, were you able to look into this?

Comment: Hi Bill.. can you create a graph gist of your data or paste the entire paths .. your query is matching.. so that it can help in analysis of the problem..

Comment: @MichaelHunger: Has there been a solution to this question yet? If so, please provide it here so that the rest of us can learn from it. But if it has not yet been solved, please make the data you received available here so that others can at least understand the issue better and take a crack at it (unless the sender doesn't want it made public). Thanks.

Comment: There has been no response to this question. I can email you the database that I sent Michael if you want to take a look.